# override `DEFAULTTUNE` and other machine configuration parameters

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have a board that requires to change the `DEFEAULTTUNE`. I did this in my `conf/local.conf`. As this place actually is reserved for build host configuration as far as I understand I think that this is actually not the best suited place. What would be the right place? Changing the machine configuration of the bsp provider does not seem to be the best idea either...

Best regards and thanks for any hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was explained `DEFAULTTUNE` is an absolute classic to go into the `MACHINE` configuration file (Credits go to LetThe2nd on [yoctos' IRC](https://webchat.freenode.net/#yocto)).

Thus, the solution is to create a directory (if you don't have it, yet) inside your own layer for machine configurations:

```
mkdir meta-mylayer/conf/machine
```

Create a configuration (let's call it `mymachine.conf`) for your machine with the following content:

```
include ${TOPDIR}/../sources/meta-sunxi/conf/machine/orange-pi-zero.conf

DEFAULTTUNE = "cortexa7t-neon"
```

you most likely have to adopt the BSP provider (meta-sunxi) as well as the machine configuration file (orange-pi-zero.conf) and the `DEFAULTTUNE` to whatever you require.