# Override compatibility of recipe

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I had to override the `DEFAULTTUNE` of a machine configuration (see my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61011386/override-defaulttune-and-other-machine-configuration-parameters))

Now, I have at least one recipe (xradio from the meta-sunxi layer) that complaints that my machine configuration is (of course) not in the compatible types of that recipe:

```
xradio was skipped: incompatible with machine opi-zero-fix (not in COMPATIBLE_MACHINE)
```

So, I wonder if xradio (and maybe other recipes) can be made compatible using one of the `OVERRIDE` mechanisms or if non-compatible recipes are best made compatible with `COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_append = " opi-zero-fix"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing this question I figured that the latter option seems most suitable. Given that `COMPATIBLE_MACHINE` needs to be a regular expression appending my own machine definition simply does not work (e.g. using using COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_append`). Thus, I had to override the compatible machine in my own`xradio.bbappend`:

```
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE = "opi-zero-fix"
```

This works for now.